# I can't fix the logout function in react

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, token, logout

this is the code of the component Logout:

```
import React, { userEffect } from "react";
import {useHistory} from "react-router";

const Logout=() =>{
  const history = useHistory()
  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/logout", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "include",
      });

      if (res.status === 401 || !res) {
        window.alert("please logout later");
      } else {
        window.location.reload();
        history.push("/login");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  userEffect(() => {
    logout();
  
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  ) 
}
export default Logout;
```

and this in the app.js:

```
app.get('/logout',(req, res)=>{
  res.clearCookie('jwt', {path: '/'})
  res.status(200).send('user logged out')
})
```

when I test it in postman the msg appears that's "user logged out" but when i test it in the browser nothing appears just blank page with \logout in the url

Comment: You need to find out where in the code the behavior is not matching expectations. There is not enough information here. Learn to log lines of code (is your function not making it to the window.location.reload() line as you wish?) or learn the debugger which lets you drop breakpoints in your code and see exactly what is happening. Is your giant try/catch catching something? Is your if statement working as expected? This is how you debug things.

Comment: You have just empty div inside your logout component , what do you expect to show than?

Comment: I want to redirect to the login page